# How to make td/th tags fixed width?

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

I am trying to create a table for a website that is a fixed width, but is fixed width based on fixed width td tags, and not the entire table having a fixed width. The need for this is because I am showing and hiding some of the columns dynamically using jQuery, and using a jQuery scrolling plugin to scroll the table as it gets wider. The problem I'm running into is that when the width of the td tags makes the table wider than its containing div, the td tags start to shrink instead of maintaining their width. So far, nothing I have done has made the td tags stay the right width. You can see a jsfiddle of what I'm dealing with here:

http://jsfiddle.net/MxE9A/1/

**How do I make td tags fixed width, even when they make the table wider than its container?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use max-width, and min-width in css to define the minimum and maximum width you want to your td's to reach to.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I had actually seen that answer on another post with the same topic, but had assumed that if setting a width wasn't working, then setting a min-width wouldn't work either. I guess I'm not that familiar with tables. Thanks for the help!

Comment: For people running across this later, you can see that solution working here: http://jsfiddle.net/MxE9A/3/

Answer (score 4):

Haha, so I've never done it this way around, but here is a solution for you. Add the following:

```
tr {
    font-size: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
th, td {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Note that this will only be IE7+ compatible, but you can use tricks to get it to display correctly as [inline block in IE 7](http://grasshopperpebbles.com/css/css-inline-block-ie7-hack/).

Trick is to set them to `display: inline-block` so that they run off the end of the element (using `white-space: nowrap`).

Answer (score 2):

```
th {
  min-width:200px;
  max-width:200px
}
```

use this for fixed width for th

Comment: it seems to me like this may be the equivalent of just using `width:200px;`. Could you maybe edit your answer to add some more details on when someone might want to use this method over others (or vise versa)?